# If I SSH into a remote machine and my connection gets dropped, then is there a chance that the run I made will continue on?

Tags: ssh

Or will the run halt along with everything (though maybe partial progress could be made if I use a ">" to print progress so far to a file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process (your "run") will receive a SIGHUP and will *likely* terminate.  Not all programs terminate properly, for example, vi/m.  You can run the program with `nohup` to have the program ignore the SIGHUP signal.  For a running program, you can send it to the background with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> then type `disown`.

You should look into `screen`(1) or `tmux`(1).  These create sessions with multiple terminal windows and allow you to reattach after being disconnected.